# Class is undefined

Tags: c++

I have two classes, one called `Grocery` and the other one called `Strings`

In the *Grocery.cpp* I'm trying to use a function from the "Strings" class called : "copyString" and I get the following error:

> identifier "copyString" is undefined

The "Strings" class is just a generic Class for the base string function such as : strcmp, strcpy and so on....

In the "Grocery" class I don't want to create a "Strings" object but using It like a the "Math" class is being used in C#. Just indicating the class name and using a dot to call a function of the Class.

How can I create a class "Strings" with the same functionality as the "Math" class in C# I described above?

Thanks a lot!
Guy

Comment: Could you provide a small code sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: pictures are relatively useless (as they are missing most of the information we need). Type in the code that gives the error.

Comment: I updated my answer. If something is still not clear please let me know. I already got my answer to the question above. The one I selected V on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you have a class `Strings`, with a method `getStringLength()`, in which case you need to call `getStringLength()` on a `Strings` instance:

```
Strings s = ....;
s.getStringLength();
```

or you have a namespace `Strings` with the method, in which case you need to call it like this:

```
Strings::getStringLength();
```

If the function is not related to the `Strings` class, consider making it a non-member function, in a suitable namespace:

Strings.h:

```
namespace StringFunctions
{
  int getStringLength();
}
```

Strings.cpp:

```
StringFunctions::getStringLength() { return 42; }
```

Comment: So in order to use the class methods I must create an object? I mean this object is irrelevant and unused.

Comment: I tried using the Strings::getStringLength() too... didn't change anything.

Comment: @Guy yes. If the object is irrelevant and unused, consider making the function a free (non-member) function.

Comment: @Guy I added an example.

Comment: We didn't learn namespaces in class so it so wierd. I just didn't want all the Grocery class to contain all the Strings functions and Now I understand namespaces is the only way.

Comment: @Guy the namespace isn't strictly necessary, but it is poor practice to bring functions and other symbols into the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

From your image it looks like you're declaring `getStringLength` (a free function) and trying to use it, but defining the function as if it were a member of the type `Strings`.

Could it be that you're writing `Strings::` without really knowing why? You don't write that just because the file is called `Strings.cpp`.

A free (non-member) function doesn't have `Strings::` in front of its definition. From what you've told us so far in the comments I think that your only mistake was writing `Strings::` when you should not have done.

Comment: Hmm that's what I learnt in class but It could be. Can you explain me?

Comment: No - read [a decent C++ book](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources) where all this is covered in detail. Either you misinterpreted what you were told in class (possibly due to it being oversimplified) or the teaching material was plain wrong (which would not be unprecedented).

Answer (score 0):

1. You normally should not include .cpp files.
2. You have to include files which you want to use in file in which you want to use.

Comment: Where did he included a .cpp file?

Comment: I included only the h file I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It is now understood, Thank you.